# Login request is always 401 Unauthorized with AuthGuard

Tags: graphql, nestjs, passport.js, express-session, auth-guard

I have been following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/nestjs/setting-up-sessions-with-nestjs-passport-and-redis-210) and trying to convert it to GraphQL. I am trying to implement a NestJS + GraphQL + Passport + Express-Session solution but I am having problems with the `AuthGuard`. Sadly there is only little information on this available online. My AuthGuard looks like this

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExecutionContextHost } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/execution-context-host';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();
    const result = (await super.canActivate(
      new ExecutionContextHost([req]),
    )) as boolean;
    console.log(result);
    await super.logIn(req);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I always receive a `Unauthorized` response when trying to do a login request. I think the problem comes from my `super.canActivate` call.

Comment: What if you remove the code up to the `super.canActivate` and just add a `getRequest` method to the `LocalGuard` that creates the `GqlExecutionContext` and gets the request out of it, [as shown in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#graphql)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: This is my AuthGuard Implementation that finally worked. Overwriting getRequest and adding my input to the body fixes the problem.

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
@Injectable()
export class LocalGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const { req } = ctx.getContext();
    await super.logIn(req);
    return result;
  }

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const gqlReq = ctx.getContext().req;
    if (gqlReq) {
      const { authCredentialsInput } = ctx.getArgs();
      gqlReq.body = authCredentialsInput;
      return gqlReq;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day, there's indeed so little info out there regarding this.